# Freezing top row while sorting in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

The first column in my spreadsheet has "Last name" in the top row, which is frozen, and last names below it. I am trying to order the rows by the last name, alphabetically. How can I make Excel keep the first row on top?
It always puts "Last name" together with other names starting with "L".

Answer (score 12):

1. Click the "**Sort & Filter**" button in the "**Editing**" section under the
   "**Home**" tab.
2. Choose "**Custom Sort**."
3. Check "**My data has headers**," then customize your sort parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Turn the data into an Excel Table like this

- select the data and hit Ctrl - T
- select the data and click Insert > Table

Tick the box for "My table has headers".

Now you can use the drop-down commands in each table header to sort (and/or filter) by that column.

Comment: This is the solution I always use +1

Comment: That is amazing.  I had no idea you could do that from a CSV.